# How to find and handle binary/numerical overflow in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, integer-overflow

I am building a unit convertor program that uses the MathFP library. 
Typically unit conversion occurs in the formula of:

U1 (unit1) * K (constant) = U2 (unit2)

I want to be able to detect when the an int has over/underflowed?
How can I detect when this has occured and gracefully handle the problem. Ideally I would be looking for a generic solution, as I would want to handle overflow with primitives of type long:

The only idea I have is:

```
int largeOne = bigNum;
int largeTwo = anotherbigNum;

//complete math operation
long l = largeOne * largeTwo;
if(l > Integer.MAX_SIZE){
    System.out.println("Overflow");
    //handle error
}
```

Should I be using a different primitive data type for these conversions, such as double?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You could check if the result is negative, or positive (depending on largeOne and largeTwo signs) but it would be a guess work.</s>

---

I found another way, you could manually multiply your two numbers with an algorithm.

---

**Resources :**

- [Wikipedia - Multiplication algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm)

**On the same topic :**

- [how to write own multiplication of big numbers ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120493/how-to-write-own-multiplication-of-big-numbers)

Comment: what happens when a double overflows? does it automatically become Inf? if so could that work?

Comment: In java a long or an int doesn't overflow, it wraps around, `MAX_SIZE + 1 == MIN_SIZE`

Comment: sorry wrapping around is what I meant

Comment: I think that the two ideas combined give a more secure result, but you can't really know for sure I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to using the BigDecimal class which has much better handling for overflow/underflow than the int/long primitives in Java. The int/long values are a special case that are not classes and as a result miss out on advantages of OOP.

Comment: BifDecimal is not in CLDC, just in CDC.

Comment: I am working with J2ME, BigDecimal is only part of the Java Standard Ed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using J2SE so I forgot what is omitted in J2ME.