# string multiplication

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to multiply two strings, but I am getting the wrong answer. Any help will be appreciated:

```
public class stringmultiplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "10";
        String s2 = "20";
        int num = 0;
        for(int i = (s1.toCharArray().length); i > 0; i--)
            for(int j = (s2.toCharArray().length); j > 0; j--)
                num = (num * 10) + ((s1.toCharArray()[i - 1] - '0') * (s2.toCharArray()[j - 1] - '0'));
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean to multiply the numbers represented by two strings. Since it's an interview question, I'm not inclined to feed you the answer, but I will hint that the answer is much easier than what you've written.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to convert s1 and s2 to numbers and work with those ?

Comment: If you are referring to parsing as an integer then i am not interested in that solution as the question was to do it similar to how you do it on paper.

Comment: How do you multiply a string on paper?

Comment: Hey! Why -1? I posted solution which gives you multiplication process the same as on paper. You can't just multiply '(s1.toCharArray()[i-1]' because you'll be multiplying code of character (eg. '0' gives you 48)

Comment: This link might help for long numbers multiplication.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120493/how-to-write-own-multiplication-of-big-numbers/10532911#10532911

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number1 = "108";
        String number2 = "84";

        char[] n1 = number1.toCharArray();
        char[] n2 = number2.toCharArray();

        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n2.length; j++) {
                result += (n1[i] - '0') * (n2[j] - '0')
                        * (int) Math.pow(10, n1.length + n2.length - (i + j + 2));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

This one should be correct implementation without using integers.

Comment: can u tell me why it is (int) Math.pow(10, n1.length * 2 - (i + j + 2)? and also your solution does not work if there are more than 2 digits.

Comment: it does not work when the result is larger than the limits of a datatype. Say i need to multiply two numbers of 1000000 digits. in that case i have to use string only

Comment: Answer was given for demonstration purposes with assumption that question asked for interview preparation or homework. By no means this cod should be 'as-is' on production. Yes, it won't work on large numbers, neither on negative ones, neither on numbers with decimal point.

Comment: In that part: (int) Math.pow(10, n1.length * 2 - (i + j + 2)), why not just: (int) Math.pow(10, (i + j)) ?

Comment: Well that right for small numbers . I am doing with results in a char array. So therefore if the numbers are of 2-3 lines It can still hold it.

Comment: Petro's version doesn't work for all cases. To make it work with strings of different sizes just replace replace the Math.pow call with
Math.pow(10, n1.length + n2.length - (i + j + 2))

Comment: @dbow good catch! I fixed code to take into account case when numbers length is different.

Answer (score 2):

You're multiplying the numbers digit-wise, and you're not handling the powers of 10 correctly.

You need to first parse the strings into integers.  You're on the right track here.  You can simplify the loop indices, and you only have to call `toCharArray` once.  E.g.:

After parsing, you can multiply the integers.

EDIT: If that's not allowed, you need to implement an algorithm like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication), which is a bit more complicated.

One approach is to make an (n + 1) x (m + n) array (strictly an array of arrays), where m and n are the number of digits in each.  It will be initialized to 0, and you can use this as an area to put the rows of the immediate and final results.  These are then summed with carry.  This is obviously a näive algorithm.

E.g. for the example above:

```
int[][] intermediates = new int[3][4];
```

This is an upper bound.

Comment: is there a way that i can do it without parsing as integer?

Comment: @Jonatan, since this is interview question next answer could be possible (based on Matthew Flaschen answer): First, you are creating 10x10 matrix ands populate it with all result of multiplications of first ten digits. After that, instead of multiplying numbers you could just look into matrix value for given result (eg. for "5" and "6" that would be matrix[5][6]) and multiply by pow(10, _Here you would use indexes of characters in strings_).

Answer (score 1):

Following is the solution which i suggest, what you forgot doing there is keeping the intermediate value.

```
public class T{  
    public static void main(String[] args) {     

        char[] num1 = "127".toCharArray();     
        char[] num2 = "32".toCharArray();

        int[] intermediate = new int[num1.length];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < num1.length ; i++ )  { 

                for(int j = 0 ; j < num2.length ; j++ ) { 


                  int d1 = num1[num1.length - i - 1]-'0';
                  int d2 = num2[num2.length - j - 1]-'0';


                  intermediate[i] += d1 * d2 * (int) Math.pow(10,j);

                  System.out.printf("  %d X %d = %d\n", d1, d2, intermediate[i]);

                }     

             intermediate[i] *= (int) Math.pow(10,i);

             System.out.println(" intermediate : " + intermediate[i]);
        }     


        int sum = 0;

        for(int i : intermediate) {
            sum += i;
        }

        System.out.println("Sum is = " + sum); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Peter's Algorithm using the pow function to be a bit confusing.
Here is essentially the same algorithm.
Convert your Strings to char[]'s and then run this.

```html
public static int multiply (char A[], char B[]){
  int totalSum = 0, sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
   sum = 0;

   for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++){
    sum *= 10;
    sum += (A[i] - '0') * (B[j] - '0');
    
   }
   totalSum *=10;
   totalSum += sum;
  }

  return totalSum;
 }
```