# Java multiplying two BigInt objects

Tags: java, arrays, bigint

Theres a BigInt class and two objects num1 and num2. I have a lab assignment and i have to multiply num1 and num2. they can be an integer up to 50 digits. the class has a size and a digit.size is the number of digits in the integer that is entered and digit is an array that holds the integer.

I have to write a method that multiplies these two objects and returns the product. Im a little confused on how to start this. Ive seen examples where there are two loops and a base. I have no idea what the base would be used for.

any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of [long multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_multiplication#Long_multiplication)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120493/how-to-write-own-multiplication-of-big-numbers

Comment: I suppose using `BigInteger#multiply` is considered cheating?

Comment: cross-post: [multiplying-two-objects](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/48559-multiplying-two-objects.html)

Answer (score 2):

I assume base is decimal / hexadecimal etc., for a more general implementation...

Generally, you need to use normal long multiplication, like learned in school.

Also note that the result could be up to 100 digits in length - if you just need the 50 least significant, you could optimize the long multiplication a bit (pretty much cut it in half).

Comment: Note that contrary to the normal long division learned in school it's preferable to write the data into the output array from the get go and not create intermediary arrays. Makes the algorithm minimally more complex, but still pretty basic - heck Knuth implemented that thing in a handful lines of MIX assembly ;) As a reminder: Any multiplication of a n-place and m-place number will have at most m+n places.