# Multiplying up to 20 numbers of 30 digits

Tags: c, loops

I was given a task to multiply up to 20 numbers of 30 digits.I figured out an algorithm to multiply two numbers with 30 digits by going on the digits of both numbers in two loops with quadric complexity. (I think the best way to approach 30 digits is to store the digits of the numbers in an 2D integers array with 20 numbers and each one of them has 30 free slots to fill their digits in these slots) the result will
be stored in an array of 30 digits. Now here are my questions and problems:

1. How can I multiply more than 2 numbers of 30 digits at once? which kind of loop should I use? I figured out how to multiply only 2 numbers of 30 digits.
2. getting the numbers in which you want to multiply from the user is another issue like while getting numbers you must know that each one of these numbers has max 30 digits to fill like if I want to get the number 52 from the user I dont to enter 52 and 28 zeros after that like just 52 itself like:

Input: 520000000000000000000000000000 is WRONG

Input: 52 is RIGHT if we didnt enter 28 zeros after 52 itself.

Here is my algorithm to multiply 2 numbers with 30 digits:

```
for (i = 29; i >= 0; i--)
 {
    for (j = 29, carry_in = 0; j >= 0; j--) 
    {
        n =number_1[i] * number_2[j] + result[i] + carry_in;
        carry_in = n / 10;
        result[i] = (n % 10);
    }
    result[i] += carry_in;
 }
```

Comment: Checkout this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120493/homework-how-to-write-own-multiplication-of-big-numbers

Comment: Ever heard of the associative law? And why do you want store these numbers in an array first? And why digits on their own? Most systems are capable of handling 128bit integers.

Comment: If you have an algorithm for multiplying 2 numbers, then you automatically have an algorithm for multiplying any number of numbers.

Comment: harold how do I implement in loops?

Comment: Ryan Vincent I can only use the stdio library and I am multiplying only integers here

Comment: Multiply it just like how you do by hand. Btw the way you store each decimal digit in an array element is quite inefficient. Real bigint libraries use base 2³² (on 32-bit computers) or 2⁶⁴ (on 64-bit computers) instead

Comment: The premise that 2  20 digit numbers will fit into 30 digits is not always valid.  You should expect that the result of the multiplication can take up to (number of digits in first number + number of digits in second number) to always be able to contain the answer (as a simple example, multiply 999 * 999 <3 digits+3digits> = 998001 <6 digits>.   multiply that by 999 <3 digits> = 997002999 <9 digits>    and so forth.  so for each 30 digit multiplier, need to allow for another 30 digits in the result.

Answer (score 8):

You should implement the [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) instead. You should write your function as a `int* multiply(int* a, int* b)`, initialize your accumulating variable in `main` as one of the 20 numbers then loop `multiply` between your accumulating variable and your remaining 19 numbers.

On a side note, your result is upper-bounded by 600 digits, which is relatively small and Karatsuba will in practice be as fast as all known (FFT-based) multiplication algorithms with better asymptotic time complexity. If you have a very large number (>10^4 digits), I would use Schönhage–Strassen or one of its derivatives such as Fürer.

Comment: Lol, even before I clicked your link I guessed Math would _have_ to be part of your background.  I mean - Karatsuba? (nice algorithm)

Comment: ^Haha, good guess. Karatsuba actually follows us everywhere :) It is even the default for long integer multiplication in Python (https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c).

Comment: Very useful indeed.  I now have this question marked as favorite.